# Pythonでjsonファイル読み込み

Tags: python, python3, json

複数のjsonファイルの中の数字を読み込むときに345個のファイルを読み込みたいのに256個までしか読み取ることができません。
原因がわからないので理由と対処法を教えていただきたいです。

プログラムコード

```
import json

i = 000000000000

for file_name in ["rightleft_{:012d}_keypoints.json".format(i) for i in range(345)]:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        read_data = json.load(f)
        print(read_data['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'][21])
```

エラーコード
256個までファイルを読み込んだあとに

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

と出て

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

というエラーが出る。

プログラム初心者なので基礎的なことかもしれませんがお願いします。

Comment: 該当のファイルが有効なjsonデータでないとか、 ['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'][21] に相当するデータが無い、とか？ それぞれの行を try except で囲んでみては？

Comment: try exceptで囲んだら最後まで読み込めました！

Comment: どちらの行で、どんな状況でエラーになっていたのか、を確認しておいた方が良いですよ。

Answer (score 0):

それぞれの行を`try except`で囲んでみては？
該当のファイルが有効なjsonデータでないとか、 ['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'][21] に相当するデータが無いとか、どちらの行で、どんな状況でエラーになっていたのか、を確認してみてください。

---

<sup>この投稿は @kunif さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51914/#comment54220_51914)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>